# Single observer different events

Tags: magento2

Can we add same observer instance with different events , like

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="catalog_product_save_after_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver"/>
</event>
<event name="catalog_product_delete_after">
    <observer name="catalog_product_delete_after_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver"/>
</event>
<event name="sales_order_payment_place_end">
    <observer name="sales_order_payment_place_end_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver"/>
</event>
```

SyncObserver-> a single observer class with 3 different methods handled by different events?

Can this be done?

Comment: Why do you ask for this?

Comment: Cause i had a confusion as to , will all the methods be called based on different event trigger in a single observer

Comment: I have updated my detailed post here... http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126819/unable-to-insert-data-into-custom-table-using-model-collection need help!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement as your. I am not able to add three function in single observer. There is execute method which get executed when related event is fired and each class have only one execute. So I have created three different class. So till now  there is no any solution  for adding three function to the same observer class.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi...can u please tell how to added different events?