# Insert data into custom table when product details changed using Resource Model

Tags: magento2

I am trying to insert data into my custom table using my Model class.

Using the InstallSchema only table got created, but values are not getting added.

(only main code added)

**etc/di**

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\Data\QueueInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Queue" />
```

**Vendor\Module\etc\webapi.xml**

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
<route url="/V1/sync/getProduct" method="GET">                                    <!--route: contains the URL and a method (GET, POST, and DELETE) -->
    <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\Data\QueueInterface" method="getProductUpdate"/>   <!--service: defines the interface class and the method for handling -->
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

**Vendor\Module\Api\Data\QueueInterface.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Api\Data;
interface QueueInterface
{
    public function getProductUpdate($limit);
}
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\Queue.php**

```
 class Queue extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface, 
                                                                  \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\QueueInterface
 {
   const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;
   const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;
   const CACHE_TAG = 'tgs_queue';  //custom table name
   protected $_cacheTag = 'tgs_queue';
   protected $_eventPrefix = 'tgs_queue';

  public function getProductUpdate($limit)
  {
     ...
  }
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Queue.php**

```
class Queue extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('tgs_queue','id');
  }
}
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Queue\Collection.php**

```
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
  public function _construct()
  {
    $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Queue','Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Queue');
  }
}
```

**etc/events.xml**

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="catalog_product_save_after_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver"/>
</event>
```

**Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver.php**

```
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class SyncObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory $syncQueueFactory      
)
{
    $this->syncQueueFactory = $syncQueueFactory;
    //$this->_queue = $this->syncQueueFactory->create();
}

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $this->syncQueueFactory->productUpdate();
  }
}
```

UPDATED **Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory.php**

```
use Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory as QueueAlias;
class QueueFactory extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    protected $syncQueueFactory;

    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession, 
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,   
    QueueAlias $syncQueueFactory,    //If I keep this i get circular dependency error.
    array $data = []
    ) {
     $this->syncQueueFactory = $syncQueueFactory;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_queue = $this->syncQueueFactory->create();
parent::__construct(
        $context,
         $registry,
        //$resource,
        //$resourceCollection, 
        $data
    );
   }

public function productUpdate(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{...}
```

1) Have i used the methods and events correctly? Are my folders structures proper?

2) Why is my data not getting inserted into my custom table?

3) The purpose of this is im trying to add the product id using my custom api!

**Suggestion highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

productUpdate should not be in model class, move it to separate

Comment: Is my QueueFactory required? if not where to keep my productUpdate()?