# magento2 overcome circular dependency in model class for using create()

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

How to solve the following circular dependency error?

This is my class:

```
class QueueFactory extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
   protected $syncQueueFactory;

   public function __construct(
    QueueFactory $syncQueueFactory,
   array $data = []
   ) {
      $this->syncQueueFactory = $syncQueueFactory;
      $this->_queue = $this->syncQueueFactory->create();
  ...
```

Here, I want to declare syncQueueFactory of the model class QueueFactory

But if i give the same class in constructor naturally i get dependency error.

What is the alternate to use create()?

Comment: oh @Krishna, i just fixed that in my constructor, thought it was repeated ones as i had asked it the same very post since i dint get answer !

Comment: I undeleted the post and replied the answer to the post @Krishna

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an alias in your use statement:

```
use /Path/to/QueueFactory as QueueAlias
```

Then in your constructor you can do:

```
QueueAlias $syncQueueFactory
```

Comment: I am again getting the same error after alias name @Raphael,  Circular dependency: Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory depends on Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory and vice versa.  could you please check my file naming conventions here .http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126819/insert-data-into-custom-table-when-product-details-changed-using-resource-model

Comment: Have updated QueueFactory class, is my file naming conventions correct? Why data is not inserting in my custom table when i do any modifications to the product details?

Comment: Any update @Raphael

Answer (score 0):

You should name your model class as Queue, not QueueFactory

Comment: I think im getting confused in the file naming conventions... can you please check my complete file structure...i have in this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126819/insert-data-into-custom-table-when-product-details-changed-using-resource-model

Comment: My model class name is Queue only though...but why am i not able to insert data as said in the above link

Comment: Any updated @kandy

Comment: If you add Factory suffix to any class, Magento generates factory class by self with "create" method. see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html for details

Comment: So no need to add this $this->_queue = $this->syncQueueFactory->create();?

Comment: You should use Factory when create model, but not use model as factory

Comment: Please suggest how do i proceed with this...